# unique id user team ranking php/json

Tags: php, json

EDIT
I got it :)
It's certainly not optimize but it works:

```
$db = json_decode( file_get_contents( $location ), true );
$users = $db['users'];
$scoreTeam1 = 0;
$scoreTeam2 = 0;
$scoreTeam3 = 0;
$scoreTeam4 = 0;

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $team = $user['team'];
    $userScore = $user['userScore'];

    switch ($team) {
        case 1:
            $scoreTeam1 = $scoreTeam1 + $userScore;
            break;
        case 2:
            $scoreTeam2 = $scoreTeam2 + $userScore;
            break;
        case 3:
            $scoreTeam3 = $scoreTeam3 + $userScore;
            break;
        case 4:
            $scoreTeam4 = $scoreTeam4 + $userScore;
            break;
    }
}
```

INITIAL PROBLEM
I would like from the following json file to create a team ranking in php :

```
"users": {
    "uniqueID": {
        "team": 1,
        "userScore": 2500,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 2,
        "userScore": 1235,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 3,
        "userScore": 6582,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 4,
        "userScore": 1200,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 1,
        "userScore": 9875,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 2,
        "userScore": 500,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 3,
        "userScore": 12,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 4,
        "userScore": 695,
    }, "uniqueID": {
        "team": 1,
        "userScore": 332,
    }, etc.
}
```

I have 4 teams, I suppose I need to create 4 variables :

1. `$scoreTeam1`
2. `$scoreTeam2`
3. `$scoreTeam3`
4. `$scoreTeam4`

Could you help me to translate this :
for each uniqueID
if team == 1 scoreTeam1 +=userScore,
else if team == 2 scoreTeam2 += userScore,
etc...

Any help is more than welcome :)
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function:

```
$result = array_reduce($db['users'], function($carry, $team){
   if (isset($carry[$team['team']]) ) {
       $carry[$team['team']] = $carry[$team['team']] + $team['userScore'];
   } else {
       $carry[$team['team']] = $team['userScore'];
   }    
   return $carry;
});
```